# How to compare three dates when previous and next are always present

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar where URL has parameters with UNIX dates for previous and next something like

```
http://loc/event/getEventsJSON?start=1343536200&end=1347165000&_=1345737237933
```

I have a query where passing month as parameter allow me to get the related data from DB. For the first view I haven't problems because I use date('m') but when I move to next or previous how do I compare the dates to pass the correct one? In others words right now is August (8) if I move to next one then will be Septmeber(9) if move to previous will be July(7) how to pass the correct value to getEventsJSON() function? I'm using FullCalendar!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure about '1345737237933'? '1345737237' (without the 933) looks more correct to me, so probably it's milliseconds since unix 0-time?

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem Well if I do this print_r(explode('-', date('c', $_GET['start']))); I get the YYYY, m, d values correctly

Comment: Try to do the same with $_GET['_']. You'll get 10/05/14 03:58:05

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem what's your point here?

Comment: My point being that 1) the start & end dates are seconds till unix-time 0, and _ is milliseconds till unixtime 0. 2) I don't understand the question probably ... What is supposed to be a correct value? What are you expecting to see and what are you seeing?

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem Ahh ok, first my PHP function takes $month as argument. For the default view isn't a problem because I get it by date('m') but when I move to next or previous start the problem because I need to compare the actual month with the ones in end or start and them pass to my function but isn't clear for me how to do this this is what I'm trying to figure out